# api performance slow

Tags: support

this query takes ~30 seconds. Seems abnormal to me

http://api.stackapps.com/1.0/users/14/questions?pagesize=100&answers=true&body=true&comments=true&page=1

Comment: The result is really large...maybe it just takes that long...

Comment: [This query](http://api.stackapps.com/1.0/users/14/questions?pagesize=100&answers=false&body=false&comments=false&page=1) returns almost instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its slow because the response is so large, and it touches a large amount of data per-question (all answers and comments, by definition).

Its equivalent to visiting every question on the first couple pages of SO, after all.